# Why need messageId in AMQP?

Tags: amqp, spring-amqp

In the Spring AMQP Project,
if messageProperties does not have messageId, they always create messageId.

Like This..

```
if (this.createMessageIds && messageProperties.getMessageId()==null) {
  messageProperties.setMessageId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}
```

I want to know what messageId is. So, I try to find out where messageId is used. But I couldn't find it in Spring AMQP Source.

What happens if messageId does not exist?
Why is messageId needed in AMQP?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The message id is only created if the converter's `createMessageIds` is true - it is false by default.

It is normally not required, unless you are using stateful retry on the consumer side.

When using stateful retry and a delivery fails, the message is rejected and redelivered by the broker. Since RabbitMQ does not include the number of retries in a header, we have to keep track of how many times the delivery has been attempted so that we can give up after the `maxAttempts` is reached. The message id is used to look up the retry state for this message.